# c++ cout uncasted memory (void)

Tags: c++, casting, cout

This is the scenario;

```
// I have created a buffer
void *buffer = operator new(100)

/* later some data from a different buffer is put into the buffer at this pointer
by a function in an external header so I don't know what it's putting in there */

cout << buffer;
```

I want to print out the data that was put into the buffer at this pointer to see what went in. I would like to just print it out as raw ASCII, I know there will be some non-printable characters in there but I also know some legible text was pushed there.

From what I have read on the Internet `cout` can't print out uncasted data like a `void`, as opposed to an `int` or `char`. However, the compiler wont let me cast it on the fly using `(char)` for example. Should I create a seperate variable that casts the value at the pointer then `cout` that variable, or is there a way I can do this directly to save on another variable?

Comment: Any reason not to create the buffer as char* if that's what you are storing in it? char* is almost as universal as void* and you can at least print it

Comment: @MartinBeckett Because the external function called requires a void*

Comment: To tell you the truth - casting (as in the theatre or opera) is a bad idea. You usually get a diva or a dame!

Comment: @EdHeal - it's all bytes really, the rest is just window dressing!

Comment: @MartinBeckett - Are you related to Margaret Beckett (Labour MP in the UK?) - anyway I digress. Yes computers work on bytes. But those bytes have semantics - see question time - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW6PN0SjW_I&feature=related - It might amuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
char* buffer = new char[100];

std::cout << buffer; 
// at some point
delete[] buffer;
```

`void*` you only need in certain circumstances, mostly for interop with C interfaces, but this is definitely not a circumstance requiring a `void*`, which essentially loses all type information.

Comment: What if `buffer` is not null-terminated?

Comment: Not really, you could just treat the buffer as an array of chars and use `copy` + `ostream_iterator` or something.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel cout does not require null termination, hence you can copy a vector<char> to cout using std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::cout); and the vector NOT have a null terminated char at its end.

Comment: @johnathon It needs one when you pass a plain `char *`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel but as you pointed out, and i was inferring to, a char* is nothing more than an unwrapped vector<char> or string, if you know it's bounds you can easily copy it to cout

Answer (score 6):

Do something like:

```
// C++11
std::array<char,100> buf;
// use std::vector<char> for a large or dynamic buffer size

// buf.data() will return a raw pointer suitable for functions
//   expecting a void* or char*
// buf.size() returns the size of the buffer

for (char c : buf)
    std::cout << (isprint(c) ? c : '.');
```

---

```
// C++98
std::vector<char> buf(100);

// The expression `buf.empty() ? NULL : &buf[0]`
//   evaluates to a pointer suitable for functions expecting void* or char*

// The following struct needs to have external linkage
struct print_transform {
    char operator() (char c) { return isprint(c) ? c : '.'; }
};

std::transform(buf.begin(), buf.end(),
               std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""),
               print_transform());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to `char*`: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer)`.  The problem is that `void*` represents anything, so only th pointer is printed; when you cast it to `char*`, the contents of the memory are interpreted as a C-style string

Note: use `reinterpret_cast<>` instead of the C-style `(char *)` to make your intent clear and avoid subtle-and-hard-to-find bugs later

Note: of course you might get a segfault instead, as if the data is indeed not a C-style string, memory not associated with the buffer might be accessed

Update: You could allocate the memory to a `char*` buffer to begin with and it would solve your problem too: you could still call your 3rd party function (`char*` is implicitly convertible to `void*`, which I presume is the 3rd party function's parameter type) and you don't need to do the cast-ing at all.  Your best bet is to zero-out the memory and restrict the 3rd party function to copy more than 99*`sizeof(char)` bytes into your buffer to preserve the ending `'\0'` C-style string terminator

Comment: Ah I see, c++ style static_casting yes?

Comment: Why cast it from a `void*` if you can avoid the `void*` all together.

Comment: It is not static cast (that is called `static_cast<>`, but telling the compiler you want to reinterpret the data in a completely different way (and possibly suffer the consequences)

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I see no reason why the OP can't just have a `char` array in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go byte by byte you could use an unsigned char and iterate over it.

```
unsigned char* currByte = new unsigned char[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    printf("| %02X |", currByte[i]);
}
```

It's not a very modern (or even very "C++") answer but it will print it as a hex value for you.

Comment: AFAIK, this is just C.  There's no C++ anywhere in this code, even the cast is a C style cast :P

Comment: Yep it is `C` (newly added new aside). Nice and simple and to the point. :) Removed the cast in case anyone is wondering what Tony's on about.